# Error joining channel from peer: This identity is not an admin

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I know the problem "This identity is not an admin" is widely reported, but this is a specific case. I have read a lot of issues here and at Jira and I see no problem close to mine.

What I am trying to do is to join a channel from a peer in a full custom Hyperledger 1.4 network where I have not used cryptogen. The problem I am getting is exactly this one:

```sh
2019-09-25 14:02:43.340 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Error: proposal failed (err: bad proposal response 500: access denied for [JoinChain][global]: [Failed verifying that proposal's creator satisfies local MSP principal during channelless check policy with policy [Admins]: [This identity is not an admin]])
```

I know that I have to use an admin identity to make the channel connection proposal, which I am doing by enrolling as the org admin. Once it is done, I just join the peer (code below). Of course, `CORE_PEER_` variables are correctly set and `ADMIN_NAME` and `ADMIN_PASSWORD` exist.

```sh
# Get admin identity
ORG_ADMIN_HOME=/data/orgs/${ORG}/admin
ORG_ADMIN_CERT=/data/orgs/${ORG}/msp/admincerts/cert.pem
if [[ ! -d ${ORG_ADMIN_HOME} ]]; then
    echo "[INFO] Enrolling admin '${ADMIN_NAME}' with ${CA_NAME} ..."
    export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=${ORG_ADMIN_HOME}

    fabric-ca-client enroll -d -u https://${ADMIN_NAME}:${ADMIN_PASSWORD}@${CA_URL}

    mkdir -p $(dirname "${ORG_ADMIN_CERT}")
    cp ${ORG_ADMIN_HOME}/msp/signcerts/* ${ORG_ADMIN_CERT}
    mkdir ${ORG_ADMIN_HOME}/msp/admincerts
    cp ${ORG_ADMIN_HOME}/msp/signcerts/* ${ORG_ADMIN_HOME}/msp/admincerts
fi
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=${ORG_ADMIN_HOME}/msp

# Join channel
peer channel join -b ${GENESIS_FILE}
```

I got the admin identity by register it before this with another script that does the next:

```sh
# Enroll CA Admin
export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=$HOME/cas/${CA_NAME}
fabric-ca-client enroll -d -u ${ENROLLMENT_URL}

# Register ORG Admin
fabric-ca-client register -d --id.name ${ADMIN_NAME} --id.secret ${ADMIN_PASSWORD} --id.attrs "hf.Registrar.Roles=client,hf.Registrar.Attributes=*,hf.Revoker=true,hf.GenCRL=true,admin=true:ecert,abac.init=true:ecert"
```

My question is, if I registered the Org Admin and I am able to enroll as it, why do I get the `This identity is not an admin` error? Does it have any sense?

Thank you

---

**EDIT:** What I am doing right now (It is reduced, not a direct copy of the code, so there are some changes mainly related to paths and folders).

I run a container called register-org that does the following:

```sh
# Enroll as CA Admin
fabric-ca-client enroll -d -u ${ENROLLMENT_URL}

# Get CA Certs
fabric-ca-client getcacert -d -u https://${CA_URL} -M ${ORG_MSP_DIR}

# Register Org Admin
fabric-ca-client register -d --id.name ${ADMIN_NAME} --id.secret ${ADMIN_PASSWORD} --id.attrs "hf.Registrar.Roles=client,hf.Registrar.Attributes=*,hf.Revoker=true,hf.GenCRL=true,admin=true:ecert,abac.init=true:ecert"

# Enroll as Org Admin
fabric-ca-client enroll -d -u https://${ADMIN_NAME}:${ADMIN_PASSWORD}@${CA_URL}

# I download then ${ORG_ADMIN_HOME}/msp/admincerts/cert.pem and save it
```

The next container is the peer itself, where I do:

```sh
# I upload the CERT.PEM file to ${CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH}/admincerts/cert.pem

# Generate Server TLS Key and Certs
fabric-ca-client enroll -d --enrollment.profile tls -u ${ENROLLMENT_URL} -M /tmp/tls --csr.hosts ${PEER_HOST}

# Generate Client TLS Key and Certificate
fabric-ca-client enroll -d --enrollment.profile tls -u ${ENROLLMENT_URL} -M /tmp/tls --csr.hosts ${PEER_HOST}

# Enroll peer
fabric-ca-client enroll -d -u ${ENROLLMENT_URL} -M ${CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH}

# Start peer
peer node start
```

Finally, I run the join-peer-channel container, where I do:

```sh
# I upload the CERT.PEM file to ${CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH}/admincerts/cert.pem

# Enroll as Org Admin
fabric-ca-client enroll -d -u https://${ADMIN_NAME}:${ADMIN_PASS}@${CA_URL}

# Join the channel
peer channel join -b ${GENESIS_FILE}

# AND IT FAILS AGAIN.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that the admin's certificate is really in the peer's admin folder?

```
cp ${ORG_ADMIN_HOME}/msp/signcerts/* ${ORG_ADMIN_HOME}/msp/admincerts
```

Are you doing this inside the peer container/VM ?

Comment: I did not know that I have to copy also admincerts to the peer. Going to try it. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Otherwise how can the peer know it's an admin? If anyone copies its own certificate to its own admin folder but it's not on the peer, how can the peer have this information?

Comment: I thought that, as the admin is registered at the same CA, it would just check its validity with a call to it.

Comment: Ok. So my order should be: 1. Registering the org admin with the CA. 2. Register the peer with the CA. 3. Enrolling as admin from the peer. `cp ${ORG_ADMIN_HOME}/msp/signcerts/* ${ORG_ADMIN_HOME}/msp/admincerts` . 5. Enroll as the peer from the peer with a new FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=/path/to/peer. 6. Expose CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/path/to/peer/msp 7. Running the peer with peer node start. 8. On the cli, enroll as admin and set CORE_PEER_ADDRESS and other variables to the peer ones. 9. On the cli, run peer join.

Comment: Is it correct? Excuse me because of the format. This page is really ugly to share code. I do not have access to the dev enviroments anymore till Monday so I am work, so I am going to share the results as long as I can test it. Thanks again.

Comment: just put the certificate of the admin, in the peer's msp/admincerts folder.... that's all.

Comment: I am going to update my main post to copy you what I am doing right now so it's easier to see. Please, check it. Thank you.

Comment: Also I would like to upvote your answer but I can't as I do not have enough reputation